# Feed input to apt install

Tags: ubuntu, apt, docker

I'm trying to install `python3.9` in a Dockerfile based on ubuntu:20.04.  When I run `apt -y install python3.9` manually, it prompts me for the geographic area and the city corresponding to my time zone.  For me, that corresponds to options 2 and 106 (i.e., New York), respectively.  However, when I run

```bash
echo '2\n106' | apt -y install python3.9
```

`apt` outputs

```
Use of uninitialized value $_[1] in join or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/Stack.pm line 111, <STDIN> line 1.

Current default time zone: '/UTC'
```

How do I feed `apt` the input values properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the `apt install` step with `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` in the environment:

```bash
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt -y install python3.9
```

This will avoid any interactive prompts during the installation process. Then, configure the timezone separately when the package and its dependencies have finished installing.

Alternatively, set up the timezone *before* installing the Python package, eliminating the need to set `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` to anything.

The timezone is set up using the following command to create a symbolic link to the New York timezone data:

```bash
ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York /etc/localtime
```

That's if you are running from an interactive shell in the container. In a Dockerfile, you get noninteractive package installation without setting the `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` variable, regardless of what order you do these two things in.

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York /etc/localtime
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3.9
```

Note the use of `apt-get` rather than `apt`.  `apt` is for use in interactive shells, while `apt-get` can be used in scripts.